# Is there a way to generate a QR code with multiple lines of text in Oracle BI Publisher report?

Tags: qr-code, rtf, bi-publisher, oracle-bi

oracle RTF template: multi-line content in QR code

I have a requirement to implement QR code with multiple lines in oracle BI publisher report. According to oracle documentation the syntax is following:

```
<?qrcode:'Hello World'; 100?>
```

But when scanning QR code I need to see each word on new line, like

```
Hello
world
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is this in standalone version or EBS?

Answer (score 0):

**Two options:**

1. Introduce the carriage return in the XML data (field1)
2. Replace spaces with carriage returns in the template (field2)

*Note:* This will not work in EBS (E-Business Suite). EBS uses an older version of BI Publisher. The `qrcode` function was introduced in Oracle BI Publisher 12c Release 12.2.1.4, not available for EBS as of 6/1/2023.

**Example XML**

```
<label>
<field1>Hello 
World</field1>
<field2>Hello World</field2>
</label>
```

**Template**

```
<?for-each:label?>
<?field1?>
<?qrcode:field1; 100?>
<?translate(field2,’ ‘,xdoxslt:chr(13))?>
<?qrcode: translate(field2,’ ‘,xdoxslt:chr(13)); 100?>
<?end for-each?>
```

**Output**

[image: QR Output]